# Counting the number of unicyclic graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Could you help me giving me the number of unicyclic graphs with k vertices and k edges ?

I remind that a unicyclic graph with k vertices and k edges is a tree with k vertices and k-1 edges to wich we add an other one edge wich create a cycle inside this tree (so it isn't a tree anymore).

I don't succeed to find this number in any paper ? I am looking for an explicit formula.

Thank you

Comment: Labelled unicyclic graphs are counted at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689526/).

Comment: Are you (the OP) interested in counting labelled or unlabelled graphs?  Because the notions of graph isomorphism differ, so too will the counts generally differ, with a larger number for labelled than for unlabelled graphs.

Answer (score 2):

It's the sequence [A001429](http://oeis.org/A001429) in the OEIS.