# Generating functions for tail length and rho-length

Tags: generating-functions, analytic-combinatorics

I am trying to obtain generating functions for *tail length* and *rho length* of a random point in a random mapping.

Let $\phi:\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\to \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ be a random function. Consider the directed graph whose nodes are the elements $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and whose edges are the ordered pairs $(x,\phi(x))$, for all $x\in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. We start from any $u_0$ and keep iterating $\phi$, i.e. we consider the sequence $u_1=\phi(u_0), u_2=\phi(u_1), \ldots$. In fact, starting from any $u_0$, the iteration structure of $\phi$ is described by a simple path that connects to a cycle. The length of this path (measured by the number of edges) is called the tail length of $u_0$ and is denoted by $\lambda(u_0)$. The length of the cycle (measured by the number of edges or nodes) is called the cycle length of $u_0$ and is denoted by $\mu(u_0)$. We also call rho-length of $u_0$ the quantity $\rho(u_0)=\lambda(u_0) +\mu(u_0)$

In the paper entitled "[Random mapping statistics](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.50.1204&rep=rep1&type=pdf)" and in the Theorem 3, the authors obtained the expectations for these parameters. How we can obtain generating functions for these parameters?

Comment: Please provide enough context.

Comment: Great reference! +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me  point out that the  cited paper is a  landmark brilliant event
containing  profound insights  that  surpass the  MSE question  answer
format.

As  an example  we do  the calculation  of the  expected  cycle length
$\mu(u_0)$ and the tail  length $\lambda(u_0)$ using the labelled tree
function.   We  refer   the  reader  to  the  paper   as  regards  the
asymptotics.

We will provide  a closed form of the  exponential generating function
of the quantities that are involved.

The species of labelled trees has the specification
$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}\mathcal{T} = 
\mathcal{Z} \times \textsc{SET}(\mathcal{T})$$
which gives the functional equation
$$T(z) = z \exp T(z).$$

We have that $$T(z) = \sum_{n\ge 1} n^{n-1} \frac{z^n}{n!}.$$

**Cycle length.**

To compute the  expected cycle length note that  these random mappings
are sets of cycles of trees having combinatorial specification

$$\textsc{SET}
\left(\sum_{q\ge 1} \textsc{CYC}_{=q}(\mathcal{T}(\mathcal{Z}))\right).$$

Now a tree on $n$ nodes that goes into a cycle of size $q$ contributes
$nq$ to the total count so we get the species
$$\textsc{SET}
\left(\sum_{q\ge 1} 
\textsc{CYC}_{=q}(\mathcal{T}(\mathcal{V}^q\mathcal{Z}))\right).$$

It follows that the bivariate  generating function of mappings by node
count and cycle size is
$$G(z, v) = \exp\left(\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{T(v^q z)^q}{q}\right).$$

This yields for the generating function $H(z)$ of the expected cycle size
$$H(z) = \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial v} G(z,v)\right|_{v=1}.$$

This works out to
$$H(z) = \left. \exp\left(\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{T(v^q z)^q}{q}\right)
\left(\sum_{q\ge 1} 
\frac{qT(v^q z)^{q-1} T'(v^q z)q v^{q-1} z}{q}\right)
\right|_{v=1}
\\ = \exp\left(\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{T(z)^q}{q}\right)
\left(\sum_{q\ge 1} 
T(z)^{q-1} T'(z)q z\right)
\\ = \frac{z T'(z)}{(1-T(z))^2} \exp\log\frac{1}{1-T(z)}
\\ = \frac{z T'(z)}{(1-T(z))^3}.$$

We get from the functional equation
$$T'(z) = \exp(T(z)) + z \exp(T(z))  T'(z)$$
so that
$$T'(z) = \frac{\exp(T(z))}{1-z\exp(T(z))}
= \frac{T(z)/z}{1-zT(z)/z}
= \frac{1}{z} \frac{T(z)}{1-T(z)}$$
and therefore
$$H(z) = \frac{T(z)}{(1-T(z))^4}.$$

Extracting coefficients via Lagrange inversion we have
$$Q_n = n! [z^n] H(z) =
n! \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} 
\frac{T(z)}{(1-T(z))^4} dz.$$

Put $T(z)=w$ so that $z=w/\exp(w) = w\exp(-w)$ and 
$dz = \exp(-w) - w\exp(-w)$ 
to get
$$n! \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} 
\frac{\exp(w(n+1))}{w^{n+1}} 
\frac{w}{(1-w)^4} 
(\exp(-w) - w\exp(-w)) \; dw
\\ = n! \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} 
\frac{\exp(wn)}{w^{n+1}} 
\frac{w}{(1-w)^4} (1 - w) \; dw
\\ = n! \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} 
\frac{\exp(wn)}{w^{n}} 
\frac{1}{(1-w)^3} \; dw.$$

This gives the closed form
$$Q_n = \frac{1}{2}
n! \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} \frac{n^q}{q!}
(n+1-q) (n-q).$$

The average in question is
$$\frac{Q_n}{n^n \times n}.$$

The sequence $Q_n$ starts with
$$1, 10, 117, 1648, 27425, 528336, 11581885,
\\ 284878336, 7772592897, 233010784000,\ldots$$

The Maple code for verification  by total enumeration of this sequence
was as follows.

```
Q :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local ind, d, gf, pos, q, x, seen, traj, cycinit;

    if n = 1 then return v fi;

    gf := 0;

    for ind from n^n to 2*n^n-1 do
        d := convert(ind, base, n);
        d := map(l->l+1, [seq(d[q], q=1..n)]);

        q := 0;
        for pos to n do
            seen := {}; x := pos; traj := [];

            while not(x in seen) do
                traj := [op(traj), x];
                seen := seen union {x};

                x := d[x];
            od;

            cycinit := 1;
            while traj[cycinit] <> x do
                cycinit := cycinit + 1;
            od;

            q := q + nops(traj)-cycinit+1;
        od;

        gf := gf+v^q;
    od;


    gf;
end;

EX :=
proc(n)
    local T;

    T := solve(TT=z*exp(TT), TT);
    n!*coeftayl(T/(1-T)^4, z=0, n);
end;

EX2 :=
proc(n)
    n! * residue(exp(w*n)/w^n*1/(1-w)^3, w=0);
end;

EX3 :=
proc(n)
    1/2*n! * add(n^q/q!*(n+1-q)*(n-q), q=0..n-1);
end;
```

**Addendum Mon Sep 22 2019.** A better way to extract the coefficients
from $H(z)$ is not to compute the derivative of $T(z)$ and use

$$Q_n = n! [z^n] H(z) =
n! \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
\frac{z T'(z)}{(1-T(z))^3} \;  dz
\\ = n! \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n}}
\frac{T'(z)}{(1-T(z))^3} \;  dz.$$

Put $T(z)=w$ so that $z=w/\exp(w) = w\exp(-w)$ and
$dw = T'(z) \; dz$ to get

$$n! \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{\exp(nw)}{w^{n}}
\frac{1}{(1-w)^3} \;  dw.$$

We then continue as before. The standard Lagrange inversion does not
help here, we get

$$Q_n = (n-1)! [z^{n-1}] H'(z) \\ =
(n-1)! \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n}}
\left( \frac{1}{(1-T(z))^4}
+ \frac{4T(z)}{(1-T(z))^5} \right) T'(z) \; dz
\\ = (n-1)! \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{\exp(nw)}{w^{n}}
\left( \frac{1}{(1-w)^4}
+ \frac{4w}{(1-w)^5} \right) \; dw.$$

This yields

$$(n-1)! \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} \frac{n^q}{q!} {n-1-q+3\choose 3}
+ 4(n-1)! \sum_{q=0}^{n-2} \frac{n^q}{q!} {n-2-q+4\choose 4}
\\ = (n-1)! \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} \frac{n^q}{q!} {n-q+2\choose 3}
+ 4(n-1)! \sum_{q=0}^{n-2} \frac{n^q}{q!} {n-q+2\choose 4}.$$

With

$${n-q+2\choose 3} + 4 {n-q+2\choose 4}
= {n-q+2\choose 3} + (n-q-1) {n-q+2\choose 3}$$

we find

$$(n-1)! \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} \frac{n^q}{q!}
(n-q) {n-q+2\choose 3}.$$

**Tail length.**

This requires  a modification to the  tree function in  order to count
the total tail length for all nodes in the tree.

We obtain the functional equation
$$T(z, v) = z\sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{T(vz,v)^q}{q!}
= z\exp(T(vz, v)).$$

This is  because when we  attach a  set of trees  to the new  root all
nodes in the tree have their tail length incremented by one.

We then have the a simple species for average tail lengths: 
$$\textsc{SET} \left(\textsc{CYC}(\mathcal{T})\right).$$

It follows that the bivariate  generating function of mappings by node
count and tail length is
$$G(z, v) = \exp\log\frac{1}{1-T(z,v)}
= \frac{1}{1-T(z,v)}.$$

This yields  for the generating  function $H(z)$ of the  expected tail
length (same as before)
$$H(z) = \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial v} G(z,v)\right|_{v=1}.$$

This works out to
$$H(z) = \left.\frac{1}{(1-T(z,v))^2} 
\frac{\partial}{\partial v} T(z,v)
\right|_{v=1}
= \frac{1}{(1-T(z,v))^2}
\left.z\exp T(vz, v)
\left(z \frac{\partial}{\partial z} T(z,v)+
\frac{\partial}{\partial v} T(z,v)
\right)\right|_{v=1}
\\ = \frac{T(z)}{(1-T(z))^2}
(z T'(z) + H(z) (1-T(z))^2)
\\ = \frac{z T(z) T'(z)}{(1-T(z))^2} + H(z) T(z).$$

This yields
$$H(z) = \frac{z T(z) T'(z)}{(1-T(z))^3}
= \frac{T(z)^2}{(1-T(z))^4}.$$

The Lagrange inversion  computation can be carried out  as before with
an extra $w$ in the integrand and it produces
$$Q_n = \frac{1}{2}
n! \sum_{q=0}^{n-2} \frac{n^q}{q!}
(n-q) (n-1-q).$$

The sequence $Q_n$ starts with
$$0, 2, 36, 624, 11800, 248400, 5817084, 150660608, 
\\ 4285808496, 133010784000,\ldots$$

The Maple code for verification  by total enumeration of this sequence
was as follows.

```
Q :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local ind, d, gf, pos, q, x, seen, traj, cycinit;

    if n = 1 then return 1 fi;

    gf := 0;

    for ind from n^n to 2*n^n-1 do
        d := convert(ind, base, n);
        d := map(l->l+1, [seq(d[q], q=1..n)]);

        q := 0;
        for pos to n do
            seen := {}; x := pos; traj := [];

            while not(x in seen) do
                traj := [op(traj), x];
                seen := seen union {x};

                x := d[x];
            od;

            cycinit := 1;
            while traj[cycinit] <> x do
                cycinit := cycinit + 1;
            od;

            q := q + cycinit-1;
        od;

        gf := gf+v^q;
    od;


    gf;
end;

EX :=
proc(n)
    local T;

    T := solve(TT=z*exp(TT), TT);
    n!*coeftayl(T^2/(1-T)^4, z=0, n);
end;

EX2 :=
proc(n)
    n! * residue(exp(w*n)/w^(n-1)*1/(1-w)^3, w=0);
end;

EX3 :=
proc(n)
    1/2*n! * add(n^q/q!*(n-q)*(n-1-q), q=0..n-2);
end;
```

The *labelled tree function* recently appeared at this 
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938519/)
and at this
[MSE link II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1071564/)
which is closely related to the present subject.

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt reply. What about generating function for rho-length? I think it is not true to consider the sum of tail-length and cycle-length.

Comment: Hi Marko, Do you know of a good reference that explains the notation used in your answer?  Thanks!

Comment: I found this:  http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/FlSe02.pdf

Answer (score 3):

**Cycle size plus tail length.**

We will show that with these parameters being cumulative we are indeed
justified in adding the generating functions for the two cases that we
considered separately above. This matches  what is being stated in the
cited paper.

Using the  same notation  as in  the companion answer  we get  for the
generating function

$$G(z, v) = \exp\left(\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{T(v^q z, v)^q}{q}\right).$$

where  $T(z,v)$  is  the  generating  function from  the  tail  length
computation.

This yields for  the generating function $H(z)$ of  the expected cycle
size plus tail length same as in the other two answers
$$H(z) = \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial v} G(z,v)\right|_{v=1}.$$

This works out to
$$H(z) = \left. \exp\left(\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{T(v^q z, v)^q}{q}\right)
\\ \times
\left(\sum_{q\ge 1} 
\frac{qT(v^q z)^{q-1} 
\left(qz v^{q-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial z} T(z,v) +
\frac{\partial}{\partial v} T(z, v)\right)}{q}\right)
\right|_{v=1}.$$

Put $$S(z) = 
\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial v} T(z,v)
\right|_{v=1}$$

and use the functional equation to obtain
$$\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial v} T(z,v)
\right|_{v=1}
= \left.z\exp T(vz, v)
\left(z \frac{\partial}{\partial z} T(z,v)+
\frac{\partial}{\partial v} T(z,v)
\right)\right|_{v=1}
\\ = T(z) (z T'(z) + S(z))
= z T(z) T'(z) + T(z) S(z)$$

so that
$$S(z) = \frac{z T(z) T'(z)}{1-T(z)}
= \frac{T(z)^2}{(1-T(z))^2}.$$

Entering this into the equation for $H(z)$ we find
$$H(z) = \exp\left(\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{T(z)^q}{q}\right)
\left(\sum_{q\ge 1} T(z)^{q-1} 
\left(T'(z)q z + \frac{T(z)^2}{(1-T(z))^2}\right)\right)
\\ = 
\left(\frac{z T'(z)}{(1-T(z))^2} 
+ \frac{T(z)^2}{(1-T(z))^3}\right)
\exp\log\frac{1}{1-T(z)}
\\ = 
\left(\frac{T(z)+T(z)^2}{(1-T(z))^3}\right)
\exp\log\frac{1}{1-T(z)}
\\ = \frac{T(z)+T(z)^2}{(1-T(z))^4}.$$

This is the sum of the two generating functions as predicted above.

We get for the closed form
$$Q_n = 
n! \sum_{q=0}^{n-2} \frac{n^q}{q!} (n-q)^2
+ n! \frac{n^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}
\\ = n^n +
n! \sum_{q=0}^{n-2} \frac{n^q}{q!} (n-q)^2.$$

The sequence starts with
$$ 1, 12, 153, 2272, 39225, 776736, 17398969, 435538944, 
\\ 12058401393, 366021568000,\ldots$$

The Maple code for this was as follows where the reader is asked to
note certain  optimizations that have  been made in comparison  to the
first answer.

```
Q :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local ind, d, gf, pos, q, x, seen, traj;

    if n = 1 then return v fi;

    gf := 0;

    for ind from n^n to 2*n^n-1 do
        d := convert(ind, base, n);
        d := map(l->l+1, [seq(d[q], q=1..n)]);

        q := 0;
        for pos to n do
            x := pos; traj := [];

            do
                for seen to nops(traj) do
                    if traj[seen] = x then break fi;
                od;

                if seen <= nops(traj) then break fi;

                traj := [op(traj), x];
                x := d[x];
            od;

            q := q + nops(traj);
        od;

        gf := gf+v^q;
    od;


    gf;
end;

EX :=
proc(n)
    local T;

    T := solve(TT=z*exp(TT), TT);
    n!*coeftayl((T+T^2)/(1-T)^4, z=0, n);
end;

EX2 :=
proc(n)
    n! * residue(exp(w*n)*(1/w^(n-1)+1/w^n)*1/(1-w)^3, w=0);
end;

EX3 :=
proc(n)
    n^n + n! * add(n^q/q!*(n-q)^2, q=0..n-2);
end;
```

Comment: ... and to visit from time to time your answers is for me a pleasure and often very instructive! +1