# Mean number of fixed points of random function from $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ to $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, expectation

Expected value (mean) tends to confuse me lately.

> Let $ \Omega$ be the discrete space of all functions $ \omega:\{1,2,3,\dots,n\} \rightarrow\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$, $\mbox{Pr}$ is uniformly distributed.
>   Let $f$ be a random variable that counts all fixed points of all functions in $ \Omega $
>   $$ f(\omega) = |\{i \in \{1,2,3,...,n\}: \omega(i)=i\}$$

Well, I had two ideas which ended the same way.
In both of them I defined n indicators $f_1,f_2,f_3...f_n$, such that for each $ 1\leq i\leq n$, return 1 if $f(i)=i$ and 0 otherwise.
Than, the expected value is the sum of $ \sum_{i=1}^{n} f_i$

**First idea**

Looking at index i, the probability to choose i as an image is $Pr(fi=1)= \frac{1}{n}$ then the expected value is $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}...+\frac{1}{n}=\frac{n}{n}=1$

**Second idea**

For index i there is one option, and for the rest of the indexes are free to be chosen, so $Pr(fi=1) = \frac{1 \cdot n^{n-1}}{n^n}$

Then the expected value is once again the sum, which is $ n \cdot \frac{n^{n-1}}{n^n} = \frac{n}{n}=1 $

Am I on the right track or totally lost?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thanks! both of ways are correcT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By way  of enrichment  let me point  out that  this can be  done using
simple  combinatorial   species  as   shown  at  the   following  [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1463544/).

Start from the species of labelled trees has the specification
$$\mathcal{T} = 
\mathcal{Z} \times \mathfrak{P}(\mathcal{T})$$
which gives the functional equation
$$T(z) = z \exp T(z).$$

We have that $$T(z) = \sum_{n\ge 1} n^{n-1} \frac{z^n}{n!}.$$

To  compute the  expected number  of fixed  points note  that these
random  mappings are  sets  of cycles  of  trees having  combinatorial
specification

$$\mathfrak{P}
\left(\sum_{q\ge 1} 
\mathfrak{C}_{=q}(\mathcal{T}(\mathcal{Z}))\right).$$

Now observe that a fixed point is in fact the root of a tree placed in
a one-cycle. This gives the marked species

$$\mathfrak{P}
\left(\mathcal{U} \mathfrak{C}_{=1}(\mathcal{T}(\mathcal{Z}))
+ \mathfrak{C}_{\ge 2}(\mathcal{T}(\mathcal{Z}))\right).$$

We get the generating function

$$G(z, u) =
\exp\left(u T(z) + \sum_{q\ge 2} \frac{T(z)^q}{q}\right)
\\ = \exp\left(u T(z) - T(z) + \sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{T(z)^q}{q}\right)
\\ = \exp\left(u T(z) - T(z) + \log\frac{1}{1-T(z)}\right)
\\ = \frac{1}{1-T(z)} \exp(uT(z)-T(z)).$$

To get the expectation compute

$$\left. \frac{\partial}{\partial u} G(z, u)\right|_{u=1}$$

which yields

$$\left. \frac{1}{1-T(z)} \exp(uT(z)-T(z)) T(z)
\right|_{u=1}
= \frac{T(z)}{1-T(z)}.$$

The desired value is then given by

$$n^{-n} \times n! \times [z^n] \frac{T(z)}{1-T(z)}
= \frac{n^{-n}\times n!}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \frac{T(z)}{1-T(z)} \; dz.$$

Putting $w=T(z)$ we get from the functional equation $w=z\exp(w)$
or $z=w\exp(-w)$ and $dz = (\exp(-w)-w\exp(-w)) dw$ which yields

$$\frac{n^{-n}\times n!}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{\exp(w(n+1))}{w^{n+1}} 
\frac{w}{1-w} \exp(-w)(1-w) \; dw
\\ = \frac{n^{-n}\times n!}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{\exp(wn)}{w^{n}}  \; dw
\\ = n^{-n} \times n! \times \frac{n^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}
= n^{-1} \times n = 1.$$

The purpose  here was to  introduce the species  which can be  used to
extract a variety of additional non-trivial statistics.