# Finding exponential generating function of the family of specific trees using symbolic method

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, trees, permutation-cycles, analytic-combinatorics

Consider the mapping-graphs given by $\mathcal{M}=Cycle(\mathcal{T})^{[∗]}$ (I'm not sure if this is read as $(Cycle(T))^{[∗]}$ or as $Cycle((T)^{[∗]})$? Which one does make more sense?), whereby $\mathcal{T}$ is the family of trees $\mathcal{T}={O}∗SET(\mathcal{T})={O}∗(\mathcal{T}^{[∗]})$.
I'd like to determine the formula for the exponential generating function M(z) with the symbolic method and calculate the number of mapping-graphs of size n.

I know that the corresponding equation for $T$
is $T(z)=z \exp(T(z))$, but I don't know how to combine this with the symbolic formula of $\mathcal{M}$, because it seems to me as if that expression would be quite complicated.
So I'd appreciate any help to get me on the right track!

Comment: This [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1463544/) contains related results and a reference.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel Thanks for the link, but it didn't bring me any further with the specific case here.

Comment: Does anyone else have any idea? I'd appreciate you sharing any thoughts on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is old, but...

We have
$$
\mathcal M = SET\left(CYC\left(\mathcal T\right)\right)
$$
so
$$
M(z) = \exp\left(\log\frac{1}{1-T(z)}\right) = \frac{1}{1-T(z)} = \frac{1}{1-ze^{T(z)}}
$$
The GF for $M$ involves the Lambert $W$ function, but we can find the coefficients using Lagrange inversion. Note that $T=ze^T$ implies $\frac{1}{1-ze^T} = zT'/T$. With $[z^n]$ meaning the coefficient at $z^n$, we get
$$
[z^n]M(z) = [z^n]z\frac{T'}{T} = [z^{n-1}]\frac{T'}{T} = [z^{n-1}](\log T)' = n[z^n]\log T
$$
Now Lagrange inversion / the Lagrange-Bürmann formula gives
$$
[z^n]M(z) = [u^{n-1}]\frac{1}{u}e^{nu} = [u^n]e^{nu} = \frac{n^n}{n!} 
$$
Et voilà(!), the number of mappings from $n$ elements to $n$ elements is equal to $n^n$. (What a waste of energy to get that answer, huh?)

Comment: Great, thank you!