# Generating function for the number of graphs with $k$ connected components

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, generating-functions

There are $$b_n = \frac{(n-1)!}{2}$$ ways to form a cycle on $n$ labelled vertices, for $n\geq 3$. The exponential generating function for this sequence is
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq 3} (n-1)! \frac{x^n}{n!} =\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq 3} \frac{x^n}{n},$$ 
and if we want the number of graphs on $n$ vertices, the components of which are cycles, the EGF is
$$ g(x) = \exp(f(x)) = \exp \left(\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{x^n}{n} - \frac{x}{2} - \frac{x^2}{4}\right)$$
$$ =\exp \left( - \frac{x}{2} - \frac{x^2}{4}\right) (1-x)^{-1/2}.$$
(This is example 5.2.8 in Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics, Vol II)

I'd like to do a similar thing with the number of connected components in a graph.

Fix $n$ and $m$, and consider the graphs on $n$ labelled vertices, with $m$ edges. (We may assume $m\ll n$.) Suppose we know there are $C_{j,l}$ ways to get a connected graph on $j$ vertices and $l$ edges. So, in particular, $C_{j,l}=0$ in case $l<j-1$, or $l>\binom{j}{2}$.

**Question:** 
Is it feasible to get an EGF for the sequence $a_k$ of the number of graphs with $k$ connected components ?

**Clarification:**
Let us use the term $(n,m)$-graph, for a graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges. We fix $n$ and $m$, and may assume that $m\ll n$. Now, there are $\binom{\binom{n}{2}}{m}$ such $(n,m)$-graphs. Let $a_k$ be the number of $(n,m)$-graphs with $k$ connected components. Clearly, $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k = \binom{\binom{n}{2}}{m}$. I'm interested in the EGF 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{k!} x^k.$$

Comment: Some material to consult at this [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689526/).

Comment: Can you clarify: $a_k$ is the number of graphs on $n$ vertices with $m$ edges and $k$ components? And you want to find $\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k\frac{x^k}{k!}$?

Comment: @MikeEarnest Correct.

Answer (score 11):

OP is asking for credible and/or official sources. We cite the **Labeled Counting Lemma** stated in *[Graphical Enumeration](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01DY7LYLY)* by F. Harary and E.M. Palmer. This lemma is important since it clarifies the usage of *exponential generating functions* and the authors just use connected, labeled  graphs with $n$ components as demonstration of this lemma.

> A theorem in section 1.2 *Connected graphs* states: The number $C_k$ of connected, labeled graphs with $k$ nodes is
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{C_k=2^{\binom{k}{2}}-\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\binom{k}{j}j2^{\binom{k-j}{2}}C_j}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

Let $C(x)$ denote the exponential generating function for the connected, labeled graphs. We find the sequence $(C_k)_{k\geq 0}$ in OEIS as *[A001187](http://oeis.org/A001187)* with generating function
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty C_k\frac{x^k}{k!}&=1+\log\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty 2^{\binom{j}{2}}\frac{x^j}{j!}\right)\\
&=1+x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + 4\frac{x^3}{3!} + 38\frac{x^4}{4!} + 728\frac{x^5}{5!}\\
&\qquad + 26\,704\frac{x^6}{6!} + 1\,866\,256\frac{x^7}{7!} + \cdots
\end{align*}

We start with a motivation for *exponential generating functions* followed by the *labeled counting lemma*.

> **Harary, Palmer: section 1.2**
>
> - It is important to have at hand the concept of the *exponential generating function* and some of its associated properties. We shall therefore introduce these functions now ...
> - For each $k=1,2,3,\ldots$, let $a_k$ be the number of ways of labeling all graphs of order $k$ which have some property $P(a)$. Then the formal power series
>     \begin{align*}
>   a(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_kx^k/k!
>   \end{align*}
>     is called the *exponential generating function* for the class of graphs at hand. Suppose also that
>     \begin{align*}
>   b(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_kx^k/k!
>   \end{align*}
>     is another exponential generating function for a class of graphs with property $P(b)$.
> - The next lemma provides a useful interpretation of the coefficients of the product $a(x)b(x)$ of these two generating functions.
>
> **Labeled Counting Lemma:** The coefficient of $x^k/k!$ in $a(x)b(x)$ is the number of ordered pairs $(G_1,G_2)$ of two disjoint graphs, where $G_1$ has property $P(a)$, $G_2$ has property $P(b)$, $k$ is the number of points in $G_1\cup G_2$ and the labels $1$ through $k$ have  been distributed over $G_1\cup G_2$.
>
> - To illustrate, let $C(x)$ be the exponential generating functions for labeled, connected graphs,
>
> \begin{align*}
> C(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty C_k x^k/k!
> \end{align*}
>
> - Then $C(x)C(x)$ is the generating function for ordered pairs of labeled, connected graphs. On dividing this series by $2$, we have the generating function for labeled graphs which have exactly two components. Similarly $C^n(x)/n!$ has as the coefficient of $x^k/k!$, the number of labeled graphs of order $k$ with exactly $n$ components. If we let $G(x)$ be the exponential generating function for labeled graphs, we then have
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{G(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty C^n(x)/n!}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

The last paragraph together with (2) reveals the connection between labeled, connected graphs and labeled graphs consisting of $n$ components. The authors close this section by presenting the functional equation connecting $G(x)$ with $C(x)$.

> Thus we have the following exponential relationship for $G(x)$ and $C(x)$ found by R.J. Riddel *[Contributions to the theory of condensation, Dissertation, 1951]*.
>
> - **Theorem:** The exponential generating function $G(x)$ and $C(x)$ for labeled graphs and labeled connected graphs come to terms in the following relation
>
> \begin{align*}
> 1+G(x)=e^{C(x)}
> \end{align*}

Comment: Upvoted. (+1). These are useful references to a classic text.

Comment: @Markus Scheuer May I please request you  to look at my [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4145394/problem-in-understanding-graph-enumeration-from-the-book-on-graphical-enumera)?

Answer (score 8):

We compute  a recurrence  for the  number of  labeled graphs  with $k$
components. With $G(z)$ the EGF of labeled graphs we have

$$G(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} 2^{n\choose 2} \frac{z^n}{n!}.$$

Here we have included the empty graph  on zero nodes. Now the class of
graphs  $\mathcal{G}$  is in  a  set-of  relationship with  the  class
$\mathcal{C}$ of connected components, namely

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\mathcal{G} = \textsc{SET}(\mathcal{C}).}$$

The class of  graphs $\mathcal{C}_k$ with $k$  connected components is
then given by

$$\mathcal{C}_{k} = \textsc{SET}_{=k}(\mathcal{C}).$$

Translating to generating functions we thus have

$$G(z) = \exp C(z)
\quad\text{or}\quad
C(z) = \log G(z)$$

and

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
C_k(z) = \frac{\log^k G(z)}{k!}.}$$

Differentiating (here $k\ge 1$) we have

$$C_k(z)' = C_{k-1}(z) \frac{G'(z)}{G(z)}
\quad\text{or}\quad
C_k(z)' G(z)  = C_{k-1}(z) G'(z).$$

Writing $$C_k(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} C_{n,k} \frac{z^n}{n!}$$

and extracting coefficients we have

$$[z^{n-1}] C_k(z)' G(z) = [z^{n-1}] C_{k-1}(z) G'(z)$$

which is

$$\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} C_{q+1, k} \frac{1}{q!}
2^{n-1-q\choose 2} \frac{1}{(n-1-q)!}
= \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} C_{q, k-1} \frac{1}{q!}
2^{n-q\choose 2} \frac{1}{(n-1-q)!}.$$

or

$$\sum_{q=0}^{n-1}  {n-1\choose q} C_{q+1, k}
2^{n-1-q\choose 2}
= \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose q} C_{q, k-1} 
2^{n-q\choose 2}.$$

This yields the recurrence

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
C_{n, k} = \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose q} C_{q, k-1} 
2^{n-q\choose 2}
- \sum_{q=0}^{n-2}  {n-1\choose q} C_{q+1, k}
2^{n-1-q\choose 2}.}$$

The base case is that when $k=0$ and $n=0$ we get the empty graph,
when $k=0$ or $n=0$ but not both we have zero. This yields
for one component the sequence

$$1, 1, 4, 38, 728, 26704, 1866256, 251548592, 
\\ 66296291072, 34496488594816, 35641657548953344, 
\\ 73354596206766622208, 301272202649664088951808, \ldots $$

which  points to  [OEIS  A001187](https://oeis.org/A001187) where  the
data are confirmed. Listing the $C_{n,k}$ in order with increasing $k$
for fixed $n$ and increasing $n$ (triangular array) we find

$$1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 38, 19, 6, 1, 728, 230, 55, 10, 1, 26704,
\\ 5098, 825, 125, 15, 1, 1866256, 207536, 20818, 2275, 245, 
\\ 21, 1, 251548592, 15891372, 925036, 64673, 5320, 434, 28, 1,
\ldots $$

which points to [OEIS  A143543](http://oeis.org/A143543), where we get
confirmation once more. The reader  who wants to experiment with these
exponential generating  functions is invited to  consult the following
Maple code.

```
CGF :=
proc(n, k)
option remember;
local G;

    G := add(2^binomial(q,2)*z^q/q!, q=0..n);
    n!*coeftayl(log(G)^k/k!, z=0, n);
end;

C :=
proc(n, k)
option remember;

    if k = 0 and n = 0 then return 1 fi;
    if k = 0 or n = 0 then return 0 fi;

    add(binomial(n-1,q)*C(q,k-1)*2^binomial(n-q,2),
        q=0..n-1)
    - add(binomial(n-1,q)*C(q+1,k)*2^binomial(n-1-q,2),
          q=0..n-2);
end;

OEIS := mx -> seq(seq(C(n,k), k=1..n), n=1..mx);
```

As a  sanity check  when we compute  $\sum_{k=1}^n C_{n,k}$  using the
values from the recurrence we really do obtain $2^{n\choose 2}.$

Comment: Great answer. Very instructive. (+1)

Answer (score 4):

It's feasible to reduce the problem to finding an exponential generating function for the number of connected graphs.

Let $C(j,l,k)$ be the number of graphs on $j$ labeled vertices and $l$ edges with $k$ components. Use the convention that an empty graph has zero components, so $C(0,0,0)=1$ and $C(0,l,k)=0$ for all other $l,k$.

Consider the component containing vertex $1$ in a graph of $n$ vertices, $m$ edges, and $k$ components. If that component has $j$ vertices and $l$ edges, there are $n-j$ vertices and $m-l$ edges left for the remaining $k-1$ components, so
\begin{align*}C(n,m,k) &= \sum_{1\in S\subset [n]}\sum_l C(|S|,l,1)\cdot C(n-|S|,m-l,k-1)\\
&= \sum_j\sum_l\binom{n}{j}C(j,l,1)\cdot C(n-j,m-l,k-1)\end{align*}
Our choice to put $1$ in the first component means $j\ge 1$ - but since $C(0,l,1)=0$, we can add $j=0$ back in and just sum over all $j$. Back to the issue at hand - yeah, that looks like an exponential-type convolution. Define $B(n,m,k)=\frac1{n!}C(n,m,k)$, and it becomes
$$B(n,m,k)=\sum_j\sum_l B(j,l,1)\cdot B(n-j,m-l,k-1)$$
Now define $f_k(x,y)=\sum_n\sum_mB(n,m,k)x^ny^m$. Our relation for the $B$ becomes
$$f_k(x,y)=f_1(x,y)\cdot f_{k-1}(x,y)$$
so $f_k(x,y)=\left(f_1(x,y)\right)^k$. Whatever the exponential generating function for connected graphs is, we raise it to the $k$th power to get the exponential generating function for $k$-component graphs.

OK, one more thing. Since every graph has some number of connected components, we can sum over $k$:
$$\frac1{1-f(x,y)} = \sum_k f^k(x,y) = \sum_{m,n}\frac1{n!}\binom{\binom{n}{2}}{m}x^ny^m = \sum_n\frac{x^n}{n!}(1+y)^{n(n-1)/2}$$
where $f$ is the EGF for the number of connected graphs and the right hand side is the EGF for the number of total graphs. I doubt the latter has an elementary closed form, so that's as far as it goes. We could solve for $f$, writing the other side as a series of powers of that generating function (minus its constant term $1$), but that's messier without any clear benefit.